# Hide text after period of time and show another in place of it and keep in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to make like a show ( continues text swapping)
so when the page is loaded the first text will disappear with animation after 3 seconds for example , and the second text will appear in place of it with animation and then disappear to show the first text and so on.

Comment: Do you? Was there a question you meant to ask somewhere? When you started to write this script what did you come up with? What problems did you have? What's your relevant "*[mcve]*" HTML? What does your script not do that it should do, what does it do that it should not do? While answering your own question is - explicitly - encouraged, you still have to ask a question that can be answered by others, who might offer alternative, or 'better' solutions.

Comment: Variations on this question have been asked a few times before. [Here is one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301783/running-text-effect) that I answered, but if you use the search you can find others.

Answer (score -3):

```
            $('#mydiv').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
            $('#mydiv2').delay(1000).fadein(500);



    <div id="mydiv"> First text**strong text**</div> 
    <div id="mydiv2" style="visibility: hidden;"> Another text</div>
```

Comment: The question asked about performing this task repeatedly in a loop.  I see no loop here.